# Threadripper + 2 GPUs and liquid cooling

Tags: cooling, video-editing

I'm getting ready to build a new video editing workstation. I've decided to use an AMD Threadripper and add a GeForce 1070 GPU, with the idea of adding potentially a second one in the future, when budget allows. I'm also adding 2 SSDs and 2 mechanical HDs in a RAID configuration.

Now, my problem is that I have never built a liquid cooling rig, but I'm a bit worried about all the heat that the above listed components will produce (specially the part about 2 GPUs in the future).

As I am not planning on overclocking this system, it doesn't *need* to be water cooled, but I do have concerns that conventional air cooling will not be enough to prevent the system from thermal throttling. I don't really have much time to spend tinkering right now and I need the new computer ASAP, so I'd like some recommendations.

I would like to keep the cost of the cooling solution below $350.

If liquid cooling, it would need to cool the CPU and GPU(s) with one reservoir and pump.

Comment: Hi, your question in its current form is more of a technical support request. If your intention is to ask for a recommendation of a compatible liquid cooling system, it would help us if you posted **specific** requirements.

Comment: In general, it would not hurt to go with a liquid cooling rig, and some come in self contained units that are easy to apply. You should be able to get away with an air cooled solution, but if you've gone through the effort of buying a pricey Nvidia GTX 1070, I would go with liquid cooling (particularly if overclocking your GPU for more performance is an idea that sounds attractive to you). I wouldn't expect an SLI GPU setup to l̶i̶g̶h̶t̶ ̶o̶n̶ ̶f̶i̶r̶e̶  hit the thermal limit and shutdown just because it was air cooled.

Comment: You might, however; lose some performance to [thermal throttling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_frequency_scaling).

Comment: @BennettYeo: thanks a lot for your answer. I realize that my question can be categorized as "opinion-based", but truthfully, I have so little idea about liquid cooling (and about the cooling needs of modern GPUs) that I wouldn't even know how to start asking specific, fact based questions. I appreciate the fact that you answered, nevertheless.

Comment: If you are looking for a recommendation for a liquid cooler, listing your GPU and a target price range should be enough. If you want, go ahead and include your CPU model and socket and we can recommend a water cooling system for your CPU as well to have a more complete water cooled system.

Comment: I agree with Bennett Yeo's suggestion of [editing](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/posts/9757/edit) this question to ask about liquid cooling instead. If you add your budget for the cooler and the case you will use, you will have enough requirements for us to recommend something that will work for you.

Comment: @Cfinley: thanks. I have reworked the question (a lot), and hopefully it's now specific enough for people to contribute.

Comment: @PaulJ Which Thread Ripper you have/plan on buying?, if the socket is AM4, I know of a full cpu/gpu water-cooling kit that supports a 1070 water-block.

Comment: @BennettYeo I thought all the Threadrippers used TR4? I'm buying either the 1900 or the 1920, depending on the budget.

Comment: A custom loop system is going to cost at least $500 (Pump, Reservoir, CPU Water-block, GPU Water-block). Is this an acceptable cost to you?

Comment: @BennettYeo Sorry, but that's a bit too much. Not so much because of the cost, but mostly because of the effort involved. If there's one thing that's clear from what I've learned so far, is that building your custom rig is a full-time hobby. I don't think I'd want to spend more than about 350$.

Comment: @PaulJ I had a feeling you'd say that. To be honest, if you're spending 500 for a custom loop you might as well buy 2 [1070's that comes water cooled (379.42 each)](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA25V5RS5282&cm_re=GTX_1070_watercooled-_-14-487-281-_-Product) and then [purchase a separate CPU water cooler (59.99)](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16835288007&cm_re=tr4_water_cooler-_-35-288-007-_-Product)

Comment: Also one more thing, [here's  a link to one of the highest rated thermal pastes on the market $10](https://www.amazon.com/Thermal-Grizzly-Kryonaut-Grease-Paste/dp/B011F7W3LU).

Comment: @PaulJ This still has a tech support feel to it. your first question is more opinion based (is it worth it will always be an opinion), and two and three are more tech support. However, I would add water cooling to the CPU, as the GPUs should be OK with their stock coolers as long as they are not overclocked.

Comment: I have edited your question to fit within the scope of the site. I believe I have kept your concerns and your requirements, but if I missed something, please either let me know or [edit] the question.